# Android Studio: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/DrawableRes.class

Tags: java, android

Kindly need your expertise. This error came up when I add **compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'** in my gradle.

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':myApp:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> >     android/support/annotation/DrawableRes.class

Here is my gradle dependencies file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.iws.iwsapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.26.7.jar')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile files('libs/mint-5.0.0.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
    compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: Run gradlew app:dependencies from command line and see if there is any duplicated dependencies

Comment: Do you really need all the Google Play services, or just identity and GCM?

Comment: try to remove this 
    compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')

Comment: @anhtuannd hi, do you have any example of the result? I already tried to run it, there is no indication of duplicated dependencies.

Comment: @cricket_007 hi, yes I need all the Google Play services.

Comment: @tamtom hi, if I remove "compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')", I cannot use : import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity; and import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;, please advice

Comment: Here is an example result of dependencies checking. If possible please include your dependencies checking in original question. 
http://pastebin.com/bC9tbgJC

Comment: So you need Google Drive, Fit, Wallet, Maps, Wear, Plus, Cast, Places, and Analytics as well as those? I somewhat doubt that. Also, if you remove the support v13 dependencies, how would what affect **support.v4** classes?

Comment: Anyways, you are compiling the Facebook SDK and this unknown "library" project. If you have overlapping dependencies, the problem likely exists in there

Comment: Can you tell me that are you using support-annotation package?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have duplicate `support/annotation/DrawableRes.class`. Make sure all your lib project:

- facebookSDK
- library

and all jar libraries under `libs` directory didn't include the `android.support.anotation` package.

If you are sure you didn't use annotation package, you can exclude annotation in your app `build.gradle` file like this.

```
android{
    ...
    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
}
```